# Conditional .then execution

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

How to conditionally skip a promise and do nothing. I have created a nested promise, by which i have 7 .then's. But conditionally, i need to skip few .then and do nothing in that block, how to achive this ?

**My FULL CODE**:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const rp = require('request-promise');

module.exports = function(req, res) {

const phone = String(req.body.phone).replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
const amount = parseInt(req.body.amount);
const couponCodeName = (req.body.couponCodeName);
const couponUsage = parseInt(req.body.couponUsage);
const usersCouponUsage = parseInt(req.body.usersCouponUsage);
const finalAddress = (req.body.finalAddress);
const planName = (req.body.planName);
const saveThisAddress = (req.body.saveThisAddress);
const orderNumber = (req.body.orderNumber);
const pay_id = (req.body.pay_id);

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri:`https://..........`,
    body: {
        amount
    },
    json: true
};

return admin.auth().getUser(phone)
.then(userRecord => {

    return rp(options)
})
.then((orderResponse) => {
    return admin.database().ref('trs/'+ phone)
        .push({ pay_id: orderResponse.id })
    })
.then(() => {
    return admin.database().ref('ors/'+ phone)
        .push({ pay_id })
})
.then(() => { 
    return saveThisAddress === true ? 
        admin.database().ref('address/'+phone)
            .push({address: finalAddress}) : null
})
.then(() => {
    return admin.database().ref('deliveryStatus/'+phone+'/'+orderNumber)
        .set({ plan: planName === "" ? "Single Day Plan" : planName, delivered: false}, () => {
            res.status(200).send({ success:true })
        })
}) 
.then(() => {
    return couponCodeName === "" ? null : 
        admin.database().ref(`couponCodes/${couponCodeName}`)
            .update({couponUsage: couponUsage + 1 })
})
.then(() => {
    return usersCouponUsage === "" ? null : 
        admin.database().ref(`couponUsage/${phone}`)
            .update({ [couponCodeName]: usersCouponUsage + 1 })
})
.catch((err) => {
    res.status(422).send({ error: err })
})    
 .catch((err) => {
 res.status(422).send({error: err });
 });
 }
```

From the above code, last two .then has a condition return couponCodeName === "" ? null : code... )}.

What i need to achieve is, when the couponCodeName === "" then, it should skip the .then block and do nothing. But, i am returning null in this, it throws an unhandled rejection error. So how to achieve this ? How to skip a .then, and do nothing ( Its important to do nothing, simply skip it ) How to do this ?

**THE ERROR I AM GETTING IS:** The error i am getting from these nested .then is "Unhandled rejection" & "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

**Error From Google Cloud Function**

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:369:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
at admin.auth.getUser.then.then.then.then.then.then.then.catch.catch (/user_code/request_payment_details.js:86:28)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

And also

```
Unhandled rejection
```

***Note: Node Js version : 6 ( So i think officially , i cant use async and await )***

Comment: Your code should work, _however_ you if usersCouponUsage is not an empty string AND one of the admin.database calls reject THEN you will end up getting the error you describe because you call `res.status(422)` in the catch after you have already done `res.status(200).send(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use `async/await` for this, as synchronization is what you need:

```
async function doSomething() {
    var res1 = await promise1();
    if (res1 === xxx) {
        var res2 = await promise2();
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you only have 1 asynchronous function that is called conditionally. (Sorry about the formatting.) `async () => { let result = false; let condition = getSystemVariableState(); if (condition) { result = await someAsyncFn(); } return result; }`. I know that even if `condition` is falsey, `async` will cause the function to return a Promise resolved to `result`, which is fine, but are there any other implications or consequences that make this a bad idea? I have searched a lot and can't find anywhere that addresses this particular issue.

Comment: @WilsonF What's the issue? An async func packs the result always into a Promises, so you can do just: `return condition ? someAsyncFn() : result;` There's no synchronization needed in your example...

Comment: That's what I suspected, but wanted to confirm I wasn't missing some further complexity of which I was unaware. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Part 1: Your error handler should not crash.

If you call `res.status(200)`, Express starts streaming data to the client (the headers are already sent). You can't change the response status afterwards with `res.status(500)`, as the status code is already on its way to the client.

```
 stuff()
 .then(result => {
   res.status(200).send(result); // server starts sending
 }).then(moreStuff) // error occurs here
 .catch(error => {
   res.status(500).send(error); // fails, as server is already sending
 });
```

To resolve this, you should only start streaming any data when all of your tasks are done:

```
 stuff().then(moreStuff).then(evenMoreStuff) // error occurs here
   .then(result => {
      res.status(200).send(result); // doesnt get executed
   }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send("Whoops, server error\n" + error.message); // works
   });
```

---

Part 2: The logic inside your error should not throw at all.

Now that the error handler works correctly you should be able to find out what's actually going wrong in your code.

(We can't help you with that without a proper error message)

---

Part 3: Implement the wanted conditional execution:

To conditionally execute promises, you have to nest them:

```
 a().then(() => {
  if(!stuff) return; // exit early, continue at next then

  return b().then(c); // conditionally execute b and c
 }).then(rest); // executes after b and c if stuff is true
```

---

Part 4: Now that everything is working, you could refactor your code to `async` / `await` to make it way more readable:

As you pointed out, v6 dpes not support `async` / `await`, you'd have to you [migrate to v8](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-8-runtime) or you [transpile it down with webpack](https://codetrest.com/ES6-async-await-google-cloud-functions):

```
module.exports = async function(req, res) {
  try {
     //...
     const userRecord = await admin.auth().getUser(phone);
     const orderResponse = await rp(options)

     await admin.database().ref('trs/'+ phone)
      .push({ pay_id: orderResponse.id });

     await admin.database().ref('ors/'+ phone)
      .push({ pay_id })

     if(saveThisAddress === true) {
       await admin.database().ref('address/'+phone)
        .push({address: finalAddress});
     }

     await admin.database().ref('deliveryStatus/'+phone+'/'+orderNumber)
      .set({ plan: planName === "" ? "Single Day Plan" : planName, delivered: false});

     if(couponCodeName !== "") {       
       await admin.database().ref(`couponCodes/${couponCodeName}`)
        .update({couponUsage: couponUsage + 1 });
     }

     if(usersCouponUsage !== "") {
       await admin.database().ref(`couponUsage/${phone}`)
        .update({ [couponCodeName]: usersCouponUsage + 1 });
     }

     res.status(200).send({ success:true });
  } catch(error) {
    console.error("Error inside API", error);
    res.status(422).send({ error });
  }
};
```

Comment: Understood, but the .then after res.status(200).send({ success:true }) is like conditional, as it returns null if couponCodeName === " " , returning null in .then is acceptable ? Can i use res.status(200).send({success:true}) for this kind of conditional .then ?

Comment: @Dazzile I'd say returning null is a bad style as it just serves no purpose.

Comment: Ya , instead of using null what should i be doing ? And , thanks for the edit, as my node version is 6, async / await function wont be supported think so (P.s : i have added this on my question ), ( i am using google cloud function , as all of my function are based on node 6 )

Comment: @dazzile you should [migrate to v8](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-8-runtime) or you [transpile it down with webpack](https://codetrest.com/ES6-async-await-google-cloud-functions)

Comment: ya will definitely do, as i have dozens of cloud function running on node 6, is there any temp solution for above prob to run, so that i can migrate slowly ?

Comment: @dazzile well v8 is downward compatible, switching to it shouldnt break anything.

Comment: Okay, checking on procedure to migrate from 6 to 8 in google cloud function

Comment: I have upgraded to v8, now i am getting error near async function ( in my vscode editor ) the error says, unexpected token function by highlighted on function

Comment: @dazzile change your linter settings to support ES7

Comment: After try, why those two alone being assigned to const and rest to await ? is there any difference ?

Comment: Have, done all the corrections. Now everything is error free, and changed everything to async/ await. But now, every await functions executes until `await admin.database().ref('deliveryStatus/'+phone+'/'+orderNumber)
      .set({ plan: planName === "" ? "Single Day Plan" : planName, delivered: false});` as data is getting stored in db, but after that i am getting 422 error again.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```js
.then(() => {
            return couponCodeName === "" ? null : 
                admin.database().ref(`couponCodes/${couponCodeName}`)
                    .update({couponUsage: couponUsage + 1 })
                .then(() => {
                            admin.database().ref(`couponUsage/${phone}`)
                                .update({ [couponCodeName]: usersCouponUsage + 1 })
                            })}
```

?

Comment: Okay, i  am returning couponCodeName === "" ? null : doing something . Is it good to return null ?

Comment: Why? Add an explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Say if you want ignore this block:

```
.then(() => {
    return admin.database().ref('deliveryStatus/'+phone+'/'+orderNumber)
        .set({ plan: planName === "" ? "Single Day Plan" : planName, delivered: false}, () => {
            res.status(200).send({ success:true })
        })
})
```

You simply return a resolved promise to go to next following then, like this:

```
.then(() => {
    if (<some-conditions>) {
       return Promise.resolve(<optional-data>);   
    } else {    // If directly want to go to first catch statement following
       return Promise.reject(<optional-data>)
    }

    return admin.database().ref('deliveryStatus/'+phone+'/'+orderNumber)
        .set({ plan: planName === "" ? "Single Day Plan" : planName, delivered: false}, () => {
            res.status(200).send({ success:true })
        })
})
```

In your case to ignore this block of code:

```
.then(() => {
    return couponCodeName === "" ? null : 
        admin.database().ref(`couponCodes/${couponCodeName}`)
            .update({couponUsage: couponUsage + 1 })
})
```

Put it like this:

```
.then(() => {
    return couponCodeName ? Promise.resolve() :      // "" and null evaluates to false
        admin.database().ref(`couponCodes/${couponCodeName}`)
            .update({couponUsage: couponUsage + 1 })
})
```

[image]

Happy Coding

Comment: That doesnt change anything at all?

Comment: @JonasWilms It works we can resolve the promise in advance to skip the then block, I have updated the answer with the snapshot.