# Chaining .then without dependency of previous results

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using node version 6, and i have chained few of .then's. But , only second .then depends on previous results, but rest of the .thens are non dependent on previous results. How to chain .then when they are not dependent on previous results.

Here is my code:

```
return admin.auth().getUser(phone)
        .then(userRecord => {

            return rp(options)
        })
        .then((orderResponse) => {
            return admin.database().ref('trans/'+ phone)
                .push({  amount: orderResponse.amount })
            })
        .then(() => {
            return admin.database().ref('ord/'+ phone)
                .push({ payment_id })
        })
        .then(() => { 
            return saveThisAddress === true ? 
                admin.database().ref('add/'+phone)
                    .push({address: finalAddress}) : null
        })
        .then(() => {
            return admin.database().ref('dStatus/'+phone+'/'+orderNumber)
                .set({ plan: planName === "" ? "Single Day Plan" : planName, orderStatus: orderStatus,
                }, () => {
                    res.status(200).send({ success:true })
                })
        }) 
        .then(() => {
            return admin.database().ref(`couponCodes/${couponCodeName}`)
                    .update({couponUsage: couponUsage + 1 })
        })
        .then(() => {
            return admin.database().ref(`couponUsage/${phone}`)
                    .update({ [couponCodeName]: usersCouponUsage + 1 })
        })  
    .catch((err) => {
       res.status(422).send({error: err });
    });
```

Few said that, i am misusing promises. What am i doing wrong ? How to handle multiple .then when each .then isnt dependent on previous results ? AS i am using node 6, async / await cant be used here.

Please guide

Comment: What do you mean by "*isnt dependent on previous results*"? Do you not want to wait for the previous result, and run all stuff concurrently?

Comment: Node 6 is EOL next month, by the way.

Comment: "*Few said that I am misusing promises.*" - who said that, where, and what did they say exactly, did they give a reasoning? Do you have a link, a quote?

Comment: See related question of OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204594/conditional-then-execution

Comment: Rolling back is way easier if you do transactions in order.

Comment: No, each .then doesn't depend on previous result, so it dont need to wait @Bergi

Comment: Yes, on my previous question, Few said that every returns are pointless, These are the exact words said **Most of those returns are pointless as you're using .then(() => ...) where the continuations don't have a parameter. This is misuse of promises. Promises aren't designed to sequence side effects; they're designed to contain asynchronous effects** @Bergi

Comment: @DazzilePro Ah, thanks. Well, they're flat wrong on that. Your code is fine (albeit a bit weird).

Comment: What you mean flat-out wrong ? @Bergi

Comment: @DazzilePro: “Promises aren’t designed to sequence side effects” is just false.

Comment: Omg, your life save. I have been spending times to figure out what am i doing wrong , cheers @Bergi. Lol, how to rewrite without weirdness ?

Comment: so what i have done above regarding chaining without previous result dependent is correct right ? @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good idea is to make use of the Promise.all function that according to [Node green](https://node.green/) it is available in Node 6.

In this case, only the second promise depends on the first one, so one way of doing it would be:

```js
var promise1 = ...
  .then(function(param) { return /* your second promise */})
var promise3 = ...;
var promise4 = ...;
var promise5 = ...;
var promise6 = ...;

Promise.all(promise1, promise3, promise4, promise5, promise6)
  .then(/* once all succeded */)
  .catch(/* if an error occurred */)
```